# I can't add data from textbox to database using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<html  ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
    <title>Testing pulling data from php file </title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('customersCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("data.php")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.names = data;
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    table, td  {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    Search: <input type="text" ng-model="query"/>
    <table  ng-controller = "customersCtrl"  >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Coutry</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:query| orderBy:'Name'">
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
            <td>{{x.City}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script>
app.controller('submit',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.submit() = function(){
        $http.post('insertdata.php',{'Name':$scope.firstname,'Country': $scope.country, 'City':$scope.city})
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log("data insert successfully");
        });
    };
});
</script>
<div style="margin-top:150px" >
    <form ng-controller="submit">
        Name:<input type="text" ng-model="firstname"/>
        Country:<input type="text" ng-model="country"/>
        City:<input type="text" ng-model="city"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-click="submit()"/>
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>



  // insertdata.php
    <?php

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

        $name =  mysql_real_escape_string($data->Name); 
        $country = mysql_real_escape_string($data->Country);
        $city = mysql_real_escape_string($data->City);
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO testing VALUES('$name','$country','$city')");
        Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 


    ?>
```

The code doesn't add the data from html to database
and I don't know why. Please help me correct the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `$scope.submit() = function(){...}` to `$scope.submit = function(){...}`?

You can check whether the request is posted correctly to PHP by inspecting the network tab in your browser.